# What is the cost of initializing an IEnumerable into a List/Queue/Stack?

Tags: c#, list, performance, optimization, ienumerable

I have a collection that could potentially have millions of elements within it. However, during certain operations, this collection may be culled and then overwritten.

I would like to know the cost of creating a new data-structure using IEnumerable, for example:

```
IEnumerable<int> collection = /* some arbitrary collection here */

/// On average, how long will this take?
List<int> converted = new List(collection);
```

This will dictate whether I will cull manually (i.e. Remove, Dequeue, Pop, etc.) or by overwriting.

The way I imagine it is handled internally is that no copying is involved making this O(1) - where the beginning is the entry-point and elements are followed accordingly - but I'm not sure.

Comment: It will take as much time as adding N items to a list, assuming the enumerable is finite. If the enumerable is infinite, it will take an infinite amount of time (well, it will crash before that, but you get the idea).

Comment: You can see the code for `List<T>` [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs#L74-L104). There's minor optimizations depending on the source.

Comment: It depends on your IEnumerable. Enumerating it can take any time. Think e.g. of cases where enumerating requires database access or slow serial I/O.

Comment: `some arbitrary collection` which one? It makes a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for `List<T>` in particular has [specific handling](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/a33b9d82d45edd2ca47db710ff06a87aa0eb9cbd/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs#L61) for `ICollection<T>`

```cs
     public List(IEnumerable<T> collection)
     {
         if (collection == null)
             ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.collection);

         if (collection is ICollection<T> c)
         {
             int count = c.Count;
             if (count == 0)
             {
                 _items = s_emptyArray;
             }
             else
             {
                 _items = new T[count];
                 c.CopyTo(_items, 0);
                 _size = count;
             }
         }
         else
         {
```

This calls through to here

```cs
     public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
     {
         // Delegate rest of error checking to Array.Copy.
         Array.Copy(_items, 0, array, arrayIndex, _size);
     }
```

which is a pretty efficient native array copy.

Other collections may have different implementations, but most do have optimizations for `ICollection<T>` because it is possible to calculate the size.

The size of an arbitrary `IEnumerable<T>` is unknowable, and may not exist until all items have been enumerated.